# Removing Selected attribute from Selectbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having one selectbox which has multiple selected attribute for options. I have one hidden variable also. based on the hidden variable value have to remove the other selected attribute to options.

```
<option value="68" >A1</option>
<option value="49" >A2</option>
<option value="69" selected="selected">A3</option>
<option value="59" selected="selected">A3</option>
<option value="79" selected="selected">A3</option>


<input type= hidden id="someId" value="69" />
```

as in the example based on hidden value 69, I have to remove the selected attributes for 59 and 79.

I can do it in Jquery

```
$(".selected").removeAttr("selected");
var new_selection = $(this).find('option:selected');
new_selection.attr("selected",true).addClass(".selected");
```

But i want in javascript. Is there any best way to do in javascript

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry I am just a learner in javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("selected").removeAttribute("selected");
var e = document.getElementById("asdf");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
e.setAttribute("selected",true);
e.classList.add("selected");
```

this is just interpreted in javascript from your jQuery code